# Code error - Saving CSV file asking to overwrite

Tags: vba, excel

My code gives me error from

```
If Dir(Pth, vbArchive) <> vbNullString Then
```

I havent been able to find the error - Can someone help me what is wrong with the code? Is it supposed to say `USERPROFILE`, or am i supposed to write something else?

```
Sub Opgave8()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim Pth As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Create default desktop path using windows user id
    user_id = Environ$("USERPROFILE")
    ' Create full path
    file_name$ = "\AdminExport.csv"
    Pth = Environ$("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\" & FileName

    Set sh = Sheets.Add

    For i = 2 To 18288
        If Left(Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12), 6) = "262015" Then
            sh.Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i

    sh.Move

    If Dir(Pth, vbArchive) <> vbNullString Then
        overwrite_question = MsgBox("File already exist, do you want to overwrite it?", vbYesNo)
    End If

    If overwrite_question = vbYes Then
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs FileName:=Pth, FileFormat:=xlCSV
            .Close False
        End With
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function UniqueRandDigits(x As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Do
        n = Int(Rnd() * 10)
        If InStr(s, n) = 0 Then
            s = s & n
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop Until i = x + 1

    UniqueRandDigits = s
End Function
```

Comment: What is the error, and what is the value of `Pth` when you debug?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code. I don't understand why you are getting an error message, but if you fix your issues, you are in a better position of finding the main problem.

1. Put `Option Explicit` at the top. If you do that, you will not do mistakes like setting the variable `file_name$` but reading from the variable `FileName`.
2. You are building a path with double backslashes. Perhaps not a big thing and it'll probably work. Add a `Debug.Print Pth` just before your troublesome `If`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> to show the debug pane and study the output. Does the printed file path exist?
3. Don't use `vbNullString`. Test with `abc <> ""` instead.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you so much for answer! Can you perhaps try to paste in the full code you mean, cause im a bit confused about several answers? :)